# Unexpected token on "export default const"

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have two different reat-native projects with exactly the same version of libraries.

But the newest one failes on "export default const", the other one not.

What is the difference between both calls?

The first one compiles correctly and is already in the app stores with the following code:

```
export default const result = [...]
```

The second one has the same package.json and failes on the same code "unexpected token (1:15) -> the position 15 is after the "default".

This is the used package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rn_simpleorm",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.32.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/react-native/node_modules/"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^15.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "jest": "^15.1.1",
    "jest-react-native": "^15.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.3.1"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are exporting a value. `const result =` isn't a value. What you want is either:

```
export default [...];
```

or:

```
const result = [...];
export default result;
```

Comment: Then why does `export default class TestClass extends React.Component {}` work?

Comment: That's a class declaration, and works differently. Similarly, `export default function foo()` works as well.

If you had tried `export default const cls = class TestClass` it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Alright, I just expected `export default` to wait for the right hand side to be compiled before continuing, that's why I didn't expect exporting classes this way to be a problem